# What is the Powershell equivalent of export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet

Tags: powershell, syntax, environment-variables

Couldn't find powershell equivalent for the below commands in the Dotnet SDK installation page.

I need to add these lines to the Powershell Profile file C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\profile.ps1

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Env:PATH = $PATH,(Join-Path -Path $HOME -ChildPath 'dotnet') | Join-String -Separator $([Io.Path]::PathSeparator)
$Env:DOTNET_ROOT = Join-Path -Path $HOME -ChildPath 'dotnet'
```

Comment: for some reason, `$Home` is recognized by powershell. The below variation works for me. Thanks! `$Env:PATH = $Env:PATH,(Join-Path -Path $HOME -ChildPath 'dotnet') | Join-String -Separator $([Io.Path]::PathSeparator)`
`$Env:DOTNET_ROOT = "$HOME/dotnet"`

Comment: lit, @blogs4t: It is the [automatic `$HOME` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#home), i.e. one automatically defined by PowerShell (but note that it is _not_ an environment variable).

Answer (score 1):

**For *Windows*, specifically** (restructured to avoid repetition):

```bash
$env:DOTNET_ROOT = "$HOME\dotnet"
$env:PATH += ";$env:DOTNET_ROOT"
```

Note:

- The `$env:` namespace prefix refers to (process-level) environment variables and the need to specify the values *in quotes*; more specifically, due to to the need for *string interpolation*, *double*-quoted string literals (`"..."`) are needed, so-called [*expandable strings*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).
- `$HOME` is PowerShell's [automatic `$HOME` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#home), i.e. a variable automatically defined by PowerShell that refer's to the current user's home directory, analogous to the `HOME` environment variable on Unix-like platforms; note that it is *not* an environment variable, however.

***Cross-platform* formulation**:

```bash
$env:DOTNET_ROOT = Join-Path $HOME dotnet
$env:PATH += [IO.Path]::PathSeparator + $env:DOTNET_ROOT
```

`Join-Path` *implicitly* uses the platform-appropriate file-system path separator (`\` vs. `/`), and `[IO.Path]::PathSeparator` returns the platform-appropriate separator for the entries of the `PATH` environment variable (`;` vs. `:`)

See also:

- The conceptual [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) help topic.
- [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path)
- [`System.IO.Path.PathSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.PathSeparator) (and [`System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))